# Conditional calculation with two datasets - PySpark

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

Imagine you have two datasets `df` and `df2` like the following:

df:

```
ID Size Condition
1   2      1
2   3      0
3   5      0 
4   7      1
```

df2:

```
 aux_ID Scalar
  1       2
  3       2
```

I want to get an output where if the condition of df is 1, we multiply the size times the scalar and then return df with the changed values.

I would want to do this as efficient as possible, perhaps avoiding the join if that's possible.

output_df:

```
ID Size Condition
1   4      1
2   3      0
3   5      0 
4   7      1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why would you want to avoid Joins in the first place. They can be efficient in there own regards.

With this said , this can be easily done with Merging the 2 datasets and building a `case-when` statement against the condition

#### Data Preparation

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""ID,Size,Condition
                1,2,1
                2,3,0
                3,5,0 
                4,7,1
        """)
    ,delimiter=','
)

    
df2 = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""aux_ID,Scalar
  1,2
  3,2
  """)
    ,delimiter=','
)


sparkDF1 = sql.createDataFrame(df1)
sparkDF2 = sql.createDataFrame(df2)

sparkDF1.show()

+---+----+---------+
| ID|Size|Condition|
+---+----+---------+
|  1|   2|        1|
|  2|   3|        0|
|  3|   5|        0|
|  4|   7|        1|
+---+----+---------+

sparkDF2.show()

+------+------+
|aux_ID|Scalar|
+------+------+
|     1|     2|
|     3|     2|
+------+------+
```

#### Case When

```
finalDF = sparkDF1.join(sparkDF2
                       ,sparkDF1['ID'] == sparkDF2['aux_ID']
                       ,'left'
          ).select(sparkDF1['*']
                   ,sparkDF2['Scalar']
                   ,sparkDF2['aux_ID']
          ).withColumn('Size_Changed',F.when( ( F.col('Condition') == 1 )
                                            & ( F.col('aux_ID').isNotNull())
                                         ,F.col('Size') * F.col('Scalar')
                                    ).otherwise(F.col('Size')
                        )
          )

finalDF.show()

+---+----+---------+------+------+------------+
| ID|Size|Condition|Scalar|aux_ID|Size_Changed|
+---+----+---------+------+------+------------+
|  1|   2|        1|     2|     1|           4|
|  3|   5|        0|     2|     3|           5|
|  2|   3|        0|  null|  null|           3|
|  4|   7|        1|  null|  null|           7|
+---+----+---------+------+------+------------+
```

You can drop the unnecessary columns , I kept them for your illustration

Comment: Was thinking of avoiding the join since it is pretty large and condition is typically 0, but this is great, thanks!

Comment: Spark optimises Joins for you as well , more info can be found here - https://luminousmen.com/post/introduction-to-pyspark-join-types